# Should you put Indexes on a SQL Table that you are updating?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a working table that we build every night with over a million records.
This procedure takes around 3 hours a night to complete.  Within the `procedure` we insert all the data into the table first.  Then we do a lot of updates to the table.

For example:

```
Update a
Set a.Field1 = b.Field1
From WorkingTable as a JOIN Table2 as b
Where a.ID = b.ID
```

At this point we do not have any Indexes or Keys assigned to `WorkingTable`.  Would it run faster if we did assign a `Index` or `Keys` to the `WorkingTable`?

Thanks

Comment: yes Use Primary Key on `ID`

Comment: I would try, measure and compare. I believe there is no definitive answer. Seems that index on `a.ID` (unique at best) could help.

Comment: Generally, insert/delete are slower with indexes on table. Update are faster depending on indexes and WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this question, you need to first know how keys and indexes work under the hood in SQL server.

A primary key, by default, is a clustered unique index. While this does slow down inserting records, the slowdown should be minimal. The real drop in performance usually comes from a `where` clause in a SQL query or DML statement that causes a table scan. If you update enough records after the initial creation, then adding a primary key or clustered unique index on the `id` columns will be a performance win.

Really the decision to use a primary key or an index comes down to this question:

> Who generates the "id"? The application loading the data or the database?

If the application loading the data generates the "id" values, then adding a clustered index on that column should be enough.

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_WorkTable_ID 
ON dbo.WorkTable (ID);
```

If the database is generating these values, just make the "id" column a primary key of type `int`:

```
ALTER TABLE [WorkTable] ADD ID INT IDENTITY(1,1);
```

Inserts, updates and deletes will still be pretty darn quick with a primary key.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186342.aspx):

> With few exceptions, every table should have a clustered index. Besides improving query performance, a clustered index can be rebuilt or reorganized on demand to control table fragmentation. A clustered index can also be created on a view.

Related: [Clustered and Nonclustered Indexes Explained](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190457.aspx)

Indexes can be a drag on performance if you need to update the values of columns that are indexed. Every update to those column values causes SQL server to rebuild that index.

As with any performance enhancement, test it out. The proof is in the pudding.

**Conclusion**

1. Write your SQL to avoid table scans.
2. Don't create indexes on columns that have their values updated, and for columns which you do not need in a `where` clause for another query or statement
3. Avoid unnecessary joins

These are the basic performance guidelines of any SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

It may run faster and it may not. That an index exists doesn't guarantee that it will be used.

Let's say table2 in your example contains only two records. Then it would definitely make sense for the dbms to use an index on WorkingTable.id to find the two records quickly.

Now let's say table2 contains 10000 times as many records as your working table. Then it might make more sense to simply go through your working table record for record and look up the index for Table2.id. No need for an index in your working table then.

Having said this: There is no guarantee that an index would speed up things, but it might. And if it doesn't, no harm has been done either. Just as Luc M sais in the comments to your request: insert and delete are slower when there are indexes that must be cared about (but as I understand you, you are through with inserts at this point). And updates and selects *can* profit from indexes.

So yes, use indexes (on WorkingTable.id  for your example) and see if they help.

Comment: Isn't it better to always add the index in this case then? SQL can then decide whether to use it or not (SQL extremely rarely suggests a bad query plan as long as the query isn't written badly)

Comment: @Charleh: This is what I am saying. There is no guarantee the index will be used, but why not try it? (Only if there were indexes on columns that themselves would be updated, These updates would be slowed down. Otherwise either the updates get faster or stay the same. No harm done.)

Answer (score 0):

This sequence should improve performance (you will need to do accurate timings to determine that):

1. Load WorkingTable
2. Create index on ID for workingtable
3. Create index on ID for table2 ( if not already created )
4. Do your updates

To accurately measure timing ( don't do this on a production server! ):

```
CHECKPOINT
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
SET STATISTICS IO, TIME ON
```